# how to set redirect link for when user updates subscription stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

So i have the stripe subscription portal enabled on my node.js app. It is working fine, but when someone updated there plan, it says it's completed, but it doesn't redirect BACK to my app unless i hit the back button. I was wondering if when they hit confirm changes, then instead of redirceting back to the portal page, go to my app instead. here's the code i have.

```
    app.get('/create-customer-portal-session', authCheck, async (req, res) => {
    const session = await stripe.billingPortal.sessions.create({
      customer: req.session.customerid,
      return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/account',
    });
  
    res.redirect(session.url);
  });
```

haven't found anything online about this, so not sure if it is doable, but just wondering! Thanks

Comment: Asyncronous function should wait response as other codes are executed. `session` is should wait for response. Is `res.redirect()` returned as await? Though `session` has `await`, it seems `res.redirect()` executed first before `session` resolve its process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can click the Back button or the portal link (i.e., the [return_url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/sessions/create?lang=node#create_portal_session-return_url) value) to go back to your app. There is no way for Stripe portal page to automatically redirect to your page upon payment confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass something like this:

```
const portalSession = await stripeInstance.billingPortal.sessions.create({
          customer: customer_id,
          return_url: redirect_url,
          flow_data: {
            after_completion: {
              redirect: {
                return_url: redirect_url
              },
              type: "redirect"
            },
            type: "subscription_update_confirm",
            subscription_update_confirm: {
              subscription: subscription_id,
              items: [
                {
                  price: stripePriceId,
                  /**
                   * subscription_item_id: "si_xxxxxx" prefixed with an "si"
                   */
                  id: subscription_item_id,
                  quantity: 1,
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        });
```

This flow will create a checkout session to upgrade the existing customer `subscription` with the new `price_id` of the subscription product we want to update.
And then, will redirect back to the application, after subscription update is confirmed

Make sure to save the `subscription_item_id` that is associated to every `subscription_id` . Or you can fetch the `subscription_item_id` from the `subscription_id` from the Stripe API:

https://docs.stripe.com/api/subscriptions/retrieve